# Most efficient way to split a list into equal sized sublists using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, dom

Using jQuery, what's the most efficient way to split a list

```
 <ul class="columnar"><li></li>... <li></li></ul>
```

into several sublists

```
<ul class="column1"><li></li>... <li></li></ul>
<ul class="column2"><li></li>... <li></li></ul>
```

where each sublist (apart from, possibly, the last one) has n items.

I want to keep querying and manipulation of the DOM to a minimum and move the original DOM elements into the new lists rather than cloning them.

Comment: Moving them will cause lots of DOM manipulations. Best to grab the all HTML, manipulate it in memory then re-insert it in one go.

Comment: But I need to keep hold of the original elements as I'm making a form template for a .NET application, and based on previous experience I have to be careful not to remove any event listeners that may be attached to the existing DOM nodes.

Comment: @Diodeus: you could move them all to a fragment, manipulate and then put the fragment back into the DOM, reducing the number of reflows and speeding things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
var $ul = $(this),
    items = $ul.children("li"),
    itemCount = items.length,
    colHeight = Math.ceil(itemCount/3); 

// create temp DOM node to place the new lists in
var temp = $("<div></div>"),
    newUL,
    i = 1;

while($ul.children("li").length > colHeight) {
    newUL = $("<ul class=\"columns\"></ul>");
    newUL.append(items.filter(":gt(" + ((i * colHeight)-1) + ")").filter(":lt(" + colHeight + ")"));
    i++;
    temp.append(newUL.addClass("column" + i));
}
temp.children().insertAfter($ul.attr("class","columns column1"));
```

Comment: Turns out my original method is the fastest by a long way http://jsperf.com/most-efficient-way-to-split-a-list-into-equal-sized-sub

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well, not sure how efficient it is though:

```
<ul id="column">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>

<div id="columns"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        var total = $("#column li").size();
        console.log(total);
        var count = 2;
        var column = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i += count) {
            column++;
            $("#columns").append('<ul id="column' + column + '"></ul>');
            $("#column" + column).html($("#column li").splice(0, count));
        }
        $("#column").remove();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The trouble with this is that slice() clones the li's rather than using the original ones.

Comment: Perhaps splice (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) would be better than as it will remove the elements from the array and return them?

Comment: But the jQuery collection is not a true array and slice is one of the few array methods that will work on an array-like collection; splice can't be applied to a jQuery collection as far as I know

Comment: I just double-checked and it looks like splice does work, but as it's not documented I'm gonna do some more testing to make sure it doesn't clone the elements.

Comment: Glad to help, I found the question intriguing!  I'll edit the answer to reflect splice.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to take a look at an existing plugin - [multi column lists](http://codeasily.com/jquery/multi-column-list-with-jquery). The author of the plugin shows the code - you can take a look at the technique used there (a combo of CSS and splitting into smaller lists).

Comment: It looks like the plugin takes a two stage process
- goes through each item adding a class to specify which column its in
- running a jquery to select by these classes and moving those selected into the relevant column
Which I doubt is more efficient, although the plugin looks to have thought of everything and is provbbaly a better general solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:) endyourif's response above is more concise, but this may be slightly more efficient as it assembles all the fragments first and then throws them in the dom with a single replace.

```
var desiredNoOfCols = 3;
var $parent = $("<div/>")
for(var i=1;i<=desiredNoOfCols ; i++){
    $parent.append("<ul class='column" + i + "'> </ul>")
}

$("#column")
    .children()
        .each(function(index, elem){
           $parent
             .children(".column" + ((index+1) % desiredNoOfCols + 1))
                .append($(elem).detach())
         })
    .end()
    .replaceWith($parent.children())
```

Comment: Looks good. I think I'll set up a test page soon to find a winner

Comment: This doesn't work as it puts the first item in column 1, the second item in column 2 etc...